# prevent table view cells from closing after cell action

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I have two action on a table view cell like such:

[image]

After I touch them, the actions get executed but the cell goes back to its original state (closed) like such:

[image]

How can I prevent the cell from closing and keep show the actions after the touch?

Comment: You are performing this on touch or swipe?

Comment: As, according to native feature of apple it needs swipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` to show the options, if yes then it is the default swipe behavior of `UITableViewCell`. On any action on the `+` or `-` the cell will hide those options, it does not retain it's `trailingSwipeActions` and goes back to the normal visible cell state.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
```

Comment: I am, so I can't prevent it from swiping back to its original form?

Comment: I doubt that is allowed by default, you can verify with few other iOS apps.